# Why is this rails nested attributes assignment not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've a Rails model called Biography, and biography has one lifestyle.

```
class Lifestyle < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :biography
end

class Biography < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :lifestyle, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :lifestyle
end
```

And In my BiographyController I've this:

```
def update_biography
  biography = current_user.biography
  logger.debug("params are: #{params}")
  logger.debug("biography_params are: #{biography_params}")
  if biography.update(biography_params)
    render :json => biography
  else
    render :json => { :errors => biography.errors.full_messages }, :status => 400
  end
end

def biography_params
            params.require(:biography).permit(
                                      :disability, :hiv_positive, :blood_type,
                                      lifestyle_attributes: [:id, :diet, :smoke, :drink])
end
```

And this is what I get from my two logger.debug statements above:

```
params are: {"lifestyle_attributes"=>{"diet"=>"2", "smoke"=>"false", "drink"=>"2"}, "disability"=>"false", "hiv_positive"=>"false", "blood_type"=>"3", "controller"=>"biographies", "action"=>"update_biography", "id"=>"4", "biography"=>{"disability"=>"false", "hiv_positive"=>"false", "blood_type"=>"3"}}

biography_params are: {"disability"=>"false", "hiv_positive"=>"false", "blood_type"=>"3"}
```

Why is that my biography_params do not contain lifestyle_attributes even though I've accepts_nested_attributes_for statment in the Biography model, and also defining association between Biography and Lifestyle in the models?  I've also added lifestyle_attributes in the strong parameters permit list.

However, if I run this in rails console the assignment does work:

```
b = Biography.first
b.update("lifestyle_attributes"=>{"diet"=>"2", "smoke"=>"false", "drink"=>"2"})
```

Comment: your params should be `params = {"biography"=> {"first_name" => "new", "last_name" => "user", "lifestyle_attributes"=>{"diet"=>"2", "smoke"=>"false", "drink"=>"2"}}`

Comment: I do not have a form for.  I'm using backbone.js views and sending json request.  This is the header: blood_type: "3"
disability: "false"
hiv_positive: "false"
lifestyle_attributes: {diet: "2", smoke: "false", drink: "2"}

Comment: you permit only first_name and last name not blood_type, disability, hiv_positive, why? it should be permitted

Comment: I've those permitted, I just left them out when posting here for easier readability.  Main thing there is lifestyle_attributes.  I'll edit the post for the entire list above.

Comment: look at my params there should be `"biography" =>` before all as you define `params.require(:biography)`

Comment: @RajarshiDas I've to define '"biography" =>' because I've nested attributes?  Everything else gets saved if I don't have '"biography" =>'.  biography_params logger statement seems to be framing everything except the nested attributes.

Comment: yes please see my first comment how it should look like

Comment: It makes sense @RajarshiDas, but shouldn't biography_params function be framing your first comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
params = {biography: {first_name: "new", last_name: "user", disability: false, hiv_positive: false, blood_type: 3,  "lifestyle_attributes: {diet: "2", smoke: "false", drink: "2"}}
```

If you do not want `biography:` on your params you can ignore `require(:biography)` on `params.require(:biography)` to just `params.permit(...)`

Hope now it will work

You get more info on [Nested Attributes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html)

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a shot today.

Comment: deleing require statement did the trick.  Is deleting require dangerous?  What is the benefit of having it in there?  Also, its creating new lifestyle id for every update.

Comment: "Go to every controller whose actions trigger mass-assignment on that model via params" here on that model so you tell which model ... you ignore require means model is not the concern just permit

Answer (score 2):

`require` and `permit` are actually the method of `ActionController::Parameters`. The `require` which in this case is the `:biography` needs to be present in the hash you are sending from your backbone views.

The `require` method ensures that a specific parameter is present, and if it's not provided, the require method throws an error. It returns an instance of `ActionController::Parameters` for the key passed into require i.e `:biography`.

Comment: What you are saying makes sense.  But why does everything work if I remove lifestyle_attributes from permit.  if you see the logger statement of "params are:", at the end of it there is ":biography =>" even though I'm not sending it in the hash generated from backbone views.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `lifestyle_attributes` are not a part of the `biography` params hash. You *should* have:

```
params: {
   biography: {
      lifestyle_attributes: {
         ...
      }
   }
}
```

This will allow the params method to access the data properly.

To explain how it works, you need to look at how the [`ActionController::Parameters`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-permit) class works:

> Returns a new `ActionController::Parameters` instance that includes only the given filters and sets the permitted attribute for the object to true.

Each time you use `params.require(:x).permit(:y)`, it will return a new hash with *only* the permitted params. These permitted params have to be nested within the *required* param.

As you've demonstrated, this works well...

> biography_params are: `{"disability"=>"false", "hiv_positive"=>"false", "blood_type"=>"3"}`

The problem is that because `lifestyle_attributes` is **not** nested under `biography`, its parameters are not returned after you call the params method.

---

The fix for this will be in your **form**:

```
#app/views/biographies/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @biography do |f| %>
   <%= ... biography attributes %>
   <%= f.fields_for :lifestyle do |l| %>
      <%= lifestyle fields %>
   <% end %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

I don't know how you've done it currently, but somehow, you've attached `lifestyle` attributes outside of the `biography` hash.